# I ask a lot of questions pertaining to an ongoing subject in a fantasy world of mine. Should I organize my questions with a special title structure?

Tags: discussion

In one of my fantasy worlds, I have an alternate human species that makes up the population of the world.

This alternate human species has a lot of unique biological differences and features that real humans don't have and I'm trying to figure out how to explain these features in a scientific manner given that there is a possible scientific explanation for them.

Currently, I have asked 4 questions pertaining to the conceptual anatomy of my alternate humans and I am wondering if I should start using a default title for them which would go like this

**Eosi Human Anatomy Question #5** ( insert subject here )

Would this be a good thing to do?

Answer (score 1):

While numbering questions may help you organize your thoughts, imo it makes the questions less helpful for other users.

For example, one of your Eosi questions is "How to design a species with hollow breasts?". A user with the same problem can easily use this title to identify the content of the question. If you rename it to "Eosi ... #5", that ease of access is lost, and users have to click to understand what you're actually asking.

One possible workaround is to do a hybrid: number and content. Instead of "How... breasts?" or "Eosi ... #5" you could do a combination: "Eosi Question #5: Hollow Breasts?" which still puts the core question in the title.

Comment: Yeah, that's kinda what I was going for. Likewise it's become apparent that most of my questions are not socially appropriate on the worldbuilding StackExchange so I may just move to another platform.

Comment: @JordanTheCynic I think a meta post about what's "socially appropriate" could be really valuable. Consider having a direct discourse with the community: "Here's what I'm trying to achieve in my world, here's why I think I need to ask NSFW questions, is this appropriate for this site? What can I do to improve?" imo the community is still willing to help if you ask cautiously. Get their feedback on how to approach asking these questions.

Comment: I was under the impression that the worldbuilding StackExchange was more accepting of NSFW questions than r/Worldbuilding but it doesn't seem to be such.

Comment: @JordanTheCynic NSFW is fine as long as it has a legitimate world building purpose. However, in general, NSFW related topics end up not very WorldBuilding at their core and seem to fixate on certain scenarios or features just because the author wants it to be that way.